# conditional in awk while selecting a line

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Sorry if the title isn't the greatest. Let me explain and perhaps that will help:

I'm selecting a line with "User-Agent" and I want to take $(NF-6) and $(NF-5) but in some cases the line doesn't have that many tokens so I wanted to do something like I put below:

```
if (/User-Agent/$(NF-6)>0)
    /    User-Agent/{os=$(NF-6)" "$(NF-5)}
else
    /    User-Agent/{os=$NF)}
```

The syntax i'm using is definitely wrong I get:

```
awk: cmd. line:5:     if (/User-Agent/$(NF-6)>0)
awk: cmd. line:5:     ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:7:     else
awk: cmd. line:7:     ^ syntax error
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

---

Entire script if it helps:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1;
awk '
    /Internet Protocol Version 4, Src:/{ip=$(NF-4)}
    /    Time to live/{ttl++}
    /    Time to live/{sttl=$NF}
    if (/User-Agent/$(NF-6)>0)
        /    User-Agent/{os=$(NF-6)" "$(NF-5)}
    else
        /    User-Agent/{os=$NF)}
    /    User-Agent/{brow=$NF}
    /    User-Agent/{agent++}
    /    User-Agent/{stringtemp=sttl"\t"ip"\t"os"\t"brow}
    /    User-Agent/{string=(string)"\n"(stringtemp)}
    /Windows;/{windows++}
    /Linux;/{linux++}
    /Solaris;/{solaris++}
    /No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info/{count++}
    END{
        sub(/\\r.*$/, "", brow);
        print "("count")" > "temp";
        print "TTL\tIP\t\tOS\t\tBROWSER";
        print string;
        print "\nSUMMARY\n\tttl\t=\t"ttl"\n\twindow\t=\t"windows/2"\n\tlinux\t=\t"linux/2"\n\tsolaris\t=\t"solaris/2 >> "temp";
    }
' $1 > summary_$1;
sort -k2n summary_$1 | uniq > holder;
cat temp > useragents_$1;
cat holder >>  useragents_$1;
more useragents_$1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare NF variable like this to make sure that many fields are available:

```
awk '/User-Agent/ && NF > 6 {...}'
```